# Start menu 'program' management in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, start-menu

In Windows XP, I was able to access to the start menu and organize the programs into their own folders. I could have a game folder and put all the games into it. This made for a much easier display of the programs and not having to go into separate columns to list the programs. How can you do the same thing in Windows 7?

Comment: The search box on Start menu is so efficient that I never browse my programs by clicking through the menus anymore. I just hit the logo key and start typing the name of the program I need.

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do is alt-click "All Programs" and select either "Open" to rearrange programs in your user account only, or "Open All Users" to rearrange programs installed for all user accounts. Note that if you have a folder by the same name in both your start menu and the global ("All Users") start menu, they will be merged automatically when the start menu is displayed.
[image: Right click "All Programs"]

Comment: It's very important to note that there are two different folders that have your app shortcuts!

Comment: Right. I failed to explain clearly that "Open" and "Open All Users" open two completely different locations, both of which are merged to form your start menu. so depending on the install settings, the shortcut to a particular program is in one or the other.

Comment: Thank you. that worked better and easier than expected. Rodney

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 doesn't allow you to change back to your classical windows Start Menu. However, you can organize your program list. It's actually located in the following directory:

```
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
or
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
```

If you still want your classic Start Menu and don't mind installing 3rd party software, you should take a look at [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: You can replace the `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Appdata\` with just `%appdata%.

Comment: @TuxRug True, not sure why this deserves a downvote though ;)

Comment: @TuxRug: If you are going to be like that, it also includes Roaming in the environmental variable.